# ORA-01304 not available

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have been getting this error since I tried to the following command:

```
alter system set sga_target = 1512m scope=spfile;
```

I get the following message when I try type any command in sqlplus:

> ```
> SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET SGA_max_size = 1512m scope = spfile;
> ALTER SYSTEM SET SGA_max_size = 1512m scope = spfile
> *
> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
> Process ID: 0
> Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
> ```

Is there any possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: Did you do a `connect / as sysdba` first?

Comment: yes I did connect as connect / as sysdba

Comment: Is the database open? `ALTER DATABASE OPEN`

Comment: Is there an SPFILE or is the Oracle instance running on the INIT file?

Comment: There is an SPFILE stored ,I can see it one of the folders .Everything was working fine until I decided to execute the following command `alter system set sga_target = 1512m scope=spfile;` ,then I started to get the following errors, I think the problem is that the MEMORY_TARTGET is too small but it won't let me increase it

Comment: Check the alert log.  If the instance abnormally terminated, there will be an  entry in the alert log.  If you have an issue with an spfile parameter, you can change it in nomount mode via: "startup nomount; alter system set...; alter database mount; alter database open;"  alternatively: create pfile from spfile; *edit the pfile directly* create spfile from pfile; startup open;

Answer (score 4):

> **Please ensure you use the correct names for your PFILE and SPFILE. Backup both files before you start playing around with them**

## Check Instance

Start SQL*Plus (Windows) or sqlplus (*nix):

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Wed Mar 29 15:09:29 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.
```

If you are connected to an idle instance, then the instance has probably not been started (maybe due to the low SGA setting).

As a precautionary measure shutdown your instance with ABORT to ensure the instances goes down fast:

```
SQL> shutdown abort
```

## Restart database instance step by step

Then restart the database instance step by step and watch for any issues.

1. Startup SQL Plus without logging in:

   ```
   bash> sqlplus /nolog
   ```
2. Connect to the database instance:

   ```
   SQL> connect  as SYSDBA
   ```
3. Start the instance using the PFILE (editable settings) instead of the SPFILE. You can modify the SGA settings in the PFILE before you start the instance:

   ```
   SQL> STARTUP PFILE = /u01/oracle/dbs/pfile_.ora
   ```
4. Check the settings for SGA:

   ```
   SQL> show sga
   ```

   You should get something like this:

   ```
   Total System Global Area 2563887104 bytes
   Fixed Size                  2242504 bytes
   Variable Size             830474296 bytes
   Database Buffers         1723858944 bytes
   Redo Buffers                7311360 bytes
   ```
5. If the instance can start with the pfile then you can create an SPFILE from the PFILE with the following command:

   ```
   SQL> create spfile = '/u01/oracle/dbs/spfile_.ora' from pfile = '/u01/oracle/dbs/pfile_.ora'
   ```

   Continue with step 7.
6. If the instance can not start with the PFILE then you have to create a new one with the following command:

   ```
   SQL> create pfile = '/u01/oracle/dbs/pfile_.ora' from spfile = '/u01/oracle/dbs/spfile_.ora'
   ```

   Modify the SGA settings in the PFILE and start over with the startup procedure at step 1.
7. Shutdown the instance again and restart:

   ```
   SQL> Shutdown immediate
   ```
8. followed by:

   ```
   SQL> startup
   ```

Your instance should be back up and running.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer but I can't seem to find an PFILE,I'm stuck at the `SQL> STARTUP PFILE = /u01/oracle/dbs/pfile_.ora`  ,I think will just reinstall the database

Comment: Well you can create a PFILE from the existing SPFILE and then modify the PFILE manually as outlined in step 6.